# What is difference between bits/stdtr1c++.h and bits/std1c++.h header files?

Tags: c++

Both header files I used, but I did not find any difference, then why they are seperated?

Comment: FWIW, don't use either.  Only include the exact headers that you need, not a catch all.

Comment: Doesn't matter. They are internal files that you simply shouldn't include yourself. Also see [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)

Comment: I would guess the TR version also includes proposed ([experimental](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental)) functionality.

Comment: "_I did not find any difference_" - in my g++ installation there's a huge difference. The `tr1` version includes `tr1` versions of a lot of standard headers instead of the usual ones etc. And it can't be repeated enough: Don't use any of the two.